# How does the Android In-app Billing refund procedure works?

Tags: android, google-checkout

From what I have read on the developer page, Android In-app Billing doesn't support refund procedure. You have to use the Google Checkout account in order to issue a refund.

I follow these steps:

1. I create a product in the developer console, with a price of 0.50 euro.
2. I buy the item using the test account
   2.1 I test my logic
3. I refund the money using Google Checkout

My question is: Is there any involved cost in doing this? Or, in the end, my developer account and my testing account will both have the initial amount of money?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is well managed by google, your client account and your developper account will both have the initial amount of money yes.

see official doc [Here](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138001?hl=en).

it says it at the end in the "Things to remember" note ;)